# trunc compile error: sub or function not defined

Tags: excel, vba

I get the error "sub or function not defined" and the highlight is on "TRUNC" in the code below.  The TRUNC function works when I put it into an Excel cell, but not in a macro.

```
    Dim sLat As String

    sLat = **TRUNC**(ActiveCell.Value, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Trunc is not available in VBA.  You can use a function like `Int`

Answer (score 0):

Nirk is correct. You can utilize the `Format` function for VBA instead to get what you want.
So in your code, try using `Format` like this:

```
sLat = Format(Activecell.value, "0.000")
```

This returns the `Activecell.value` with 3 decimal places.
Hope this helps.